# Unity IAP services - Item already owned

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity IAP services in Unity v5.3.1p3 for Android.

I have implemented inapp purchases which seems to work fine except one bug.  If internet connection goes off when the payment is being processed, then the state goes to an inconsistent state as it is unable to send the consume event internally, which I have checked in the log.

Now, since it is unable to consume that product, so if we try to buy that product again, it shows item is already owned by me. I have checked all the API and nowhere I have found a way to consume the product explicitly.

What should I do ?

Comment: I hope you receive an answer soon.
I also suggest posting this on the Unity forums- there's a higher chance of grabbing the attention of Unity mods who will be better able to help with this. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @andeart. Yeah I have already  posted it on Unity forum but awaiting moderation since last 2 days.  I don't know what to do. :(

Comment: Can you link to that post ?

Comment: You can also consider using MobiShop (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636) it's currently not speaking with Unity's payment services but you can use it to speak directly to Apple/Google's services.